# How to create custom variables in the wp-config

Tags: variables, wp-config

I would like to add some custom config variables in the `wp-config.php` file (not in the `functions.php`). Then, I need to access to these variables in my templates.
What is the way to do that ?

Comment: Hi can you get answer of this question. please i need this functionality. thank you

Comment: I accepted the following answer, just add your custom variable with a `define`

Comment: Just FYI these are more accurately "defined constants" and not "variables".

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Why do you need this?

In wp-config you can set defines. They will be accesible everywhere without needing to use globals. Define something: `define('MY_DEFINE_NAME', 'THE_VALUE');`.

Then in your templates you can show the value like this: `echo MY_DEFINE_NAME;`

Or set the value to a variable: `$var = MY_DEFINE_NAME;`.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. I need to store some page IDs. The page IDs depend of environments (dev, production etc...). Moreover the functions.php is subversionned contrary to the wp-config.php. This is why I need to store some datas in this file.